# Age verification for Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, verification

```
if(!validateNumber($('input[name="age"]').val()) ){
        validate = false;
        $("#error_age").show();
        $('.field-row').has('input[name="age"]').addClass('haserror');
    }


function validateNumber(elementValue){
    var numPattern = /^[0-9]+$/;
    return numPattern.test(elementValue);   
}
```

Above is working code for a form in using on a competition. This isnt my code, im taking over a job and my coding knowledge is minimal.

The age input form is just age. Not DOB.

I want to be able to make it only 18 and over. How was i do this? Or whats the best way to achieve this?

Cheeers!

Comment: What does the `validateNumber` function look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function validateNumber(elementValue){
    var numPattern = /^[0-9]+$/;
    return numPattern.test(elementValue) && elementValue >= 18;   
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/br5Tc/1/)

Comment: Im going to. It says i have to wait 6 minutes! :P

Comment: `…only 18 and over` so `elementValue >= 18` or `elementValue > 17`.